# Cant upload big file via PHP

Tags: php, ajax, upload

The console shows the warning `Time over 1000ms` when I upload a file more than 10MB. All of the settings in `php.ini` are fine, but I still cannot upload to the server.

Comment: Use `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` in your script..

Comment: Anything in the error logs? Is a 500 thrown when you hit the limit?

Comment: Re Rayon, I tried to add this to my script, but it didnt work.

Comment: Re Chris, I checked my error log. 

PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 58576422 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

how can I fixed this? I already set the upload_max_filesize to 100M in WHM

Thanks all of you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable upload big files to server using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534433/unable-upload-big-files-to-server-using-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks All. After I set the `post_max_size` to 100M in my `WHM` and everything done!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update upload max size,max execution time and post max size
Update the Maximum upload size in the php.ini file.

Variable name in php.ini file

upload_max_filesize:11M
post_max_size:11M // more than 10M
max_execution_time:500