# cant upload large files

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, php-ini

I have a simple script for uploading video. it works fine with 16mb of file but larger file than that are not being uploaded. I'm using it on xampp localhost.

I have tried changing value on post_max_size and upload_max_size but it doesn'
t work.

While uploading large file nothing happens the code does not execute If part neither else. Please see code below:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload_btn']))
{

    $q3="select uid from user_profile where username='$uname'";
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($q3));
    $id=$row['uid'];

    $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $desc=$_POST['vid_desc'];

    $type_temp=$_FILES['file']['type'];
    $type=substr($type_temp,-3);

    $size=$_FILES['file']['size']/1024/1024;

    $temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    if($_POST['vid_title']=="")
    {
        $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    }
    else
    {
        $_FILES['file']['name']=$_POST['vid_title'];
        $name=$_FILES['file']['name'].".".$type;
    }

    if($_FILES['file']['type']=="video/mp4"||$_FILES['file']['type']=="video/flv"||$_FILES['file']['type']=="video/avi"&&$_FILES['file']['size']>=0)
    {

        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select uid from user_profile where username='$uname'"));
        $uid=$row['uid'];

        $query="insert into video_info(vid_title,vid_desc,vid_type,vid_size,uid) values('$name','$desc','$type','$size',$uid)";
        mysql_query($query);

        move_uploaded_file($temp,"videos/".$name);

        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = "Video uploaded successfully!!!";
        //alert("Video uploaded successfully!!!");</script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "<style='color:red;'>Format not supported!! Supported formats are .mp4, .flv, .avi";
        //alert("");</script>
        <?php
    }

}
```

Thanks and hope someone will help me figure out from this problem.

Comment: check the error codes then.

Comment: Neither error code is being executed.

Comment: `document.getElementById("error")` That isn't what I was talking about, I meant this http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: I dont see any use of the `$_FILES['file']['error']` value. If you look at that and match the code to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) you may be able to diagnose your own problems _You can lead a man to an error code, but you cannot make him read and make use of it_

Comment: @RiggsFolly what about horses?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Terrible drinkers them 'orses. All in AA

Comment: @RiggsFolly They're real sows dem 'orses *eh?*

Comment: Ohh okay thanks will check that. Thanks again for the answers (:

Comment: @NathaOdedara anytime ;-)

Comment: btw, if you're live with this, you're open to a serious SQL injection here. You stand to get seriously hacked. @NathaOdedara

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes I know and I really appreciate of your help and guidelines. But I'm just learning things with my studies and doing a project in core php. I will be improving myself day by day and as studies go on. Again Thanks.(:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable upload big files to server using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534433/unable-upload-big-files-to-server-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your php.ini files, you should have 2, one for CLI another for apache (if that is your stack). Judging by your question you edited just one php.ini file. Edit them both to suit your needs. The value you should edit is:

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Change to whatever you need. Also, this setting might interest you:

```
Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Restart apache after editing.

Comment: ___For future reference___ the space used by `max_upload_filesize` is a part of the `post_max_size` so when you increase `max_upload_filesize` make sure `post_max_size` is larger than `max_upload_filesize`. Larger because you also need to allow for space used by other `<input>` fields on a `<form>` Also `max_input_time` may need to be looked at if lots of or large files are involved

Comment: @visualex Thanks alot!! It did fixed my problem.

Comment: @NathaOdedara awesome, take into account the details commented by Riggs

Comment: Yea Thanks @RiggsFolly, I will keep that in mind. :D

Comment: @NathaOdedara please mark the right answer and close the question

Comment: @visualex marked right answer. But could not find option to close the question.